# Clarification of RSA signature verification parameters

Tags: c, linux, openssl, rsa

I have a customer supplied RSA signature verification API description that takes the parameters - Modulus(N), E, Padding scheme, salt, , message and its signature. I have to implement the signature verification API (I can leverage openssl APIs).

With the above information, can I verify signature passed ? Or I need additional parameters ?
I think I can derive public key from N and E. But what is the salt and padding scheme for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public key for RSA *is* N and E as a pair. The private key comprises p, q and d - although d can be derived knowing p, q and e.

So, in short terms: you should be able to, yes.

The additional parameters (salt, padding scheme) are so that you correctly utilise RSA in terms of PKCS #1, and correctly decode RSA signatures.

If in doubt, find an existing implementation of PKCS#1 and related standards, and use that to implement these calls.